# Tensorflow Object Detection API ValueError: No variables to save

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.6, google-colaboratory, object-detection-api

I'm trying to train a custom object detection model using tensorflow object detection api. For the training purposes I used pickled image data set for training and as model I used `ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco`. When I started the training it gave me this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 184, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 126, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "train.py", line 180, in main
    graph_hook_fn=graph_rewriter_fn)
  File "/content/models/research/object_detection/trainer.py", line 381, in train
    init_saver = tf.train.Saver(available_var_map)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1338, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1347, in build
    self._build(self._filename, build_save=True, build_restore=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1372, in _build
    raise ValueError("No variables to save")
ValueError: No variables to save
```

Full error code can find here...

```
[https://gist.github.com/mpgovinda/1f59f7de7873f6ec4c4426b79dc6827a][1]
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Tested Solution

Add `fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"` to `train_config: { ... }` section in your `*.config` file.

### Sample

```ini
train_config: {
  ...
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "./pre_trained_model/model.ckpt"
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type:  "detection"
  ...
}
```

Tested on `ssd_mobilenet_v1_quantized_300x300_coco14_sync` model.

Answer (score 2):

Was training this model http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29.tar.gz

Ran into the same error. Don't really like others' solution of setting `from_detection_checkpoint: false`.

Was fixed by adding the `load_all_detection_checkpoint_vars: true` field in `train_config` of the `pipeline.config` that comes with the model.

I also added `from_detection_checkpoint: true` as it was not there, not sure if it was relevant to the solution.

```
fine_tune_checkpoint: "path_to_model_ckpt/model.ckpt"
from_detection_checkpoint: true
load_all_detection_checkpoint_vars: true # this here fixed it
num_steps: 200000 # irrelevant
fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"
```

Answer (score 1):

The latest models have this problem, to solve this:

Go to '.config' file of your model and in the training section change
`from_detection_checkpoint: true` to false

It will work.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: My pipeline.config nor my ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.config file had a 
"from_detection_checkpoint:" bool -- I added this under "fine_tune_checkpoint:", and changed it to false, but still have this issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error while trying to train faster-rcnn with inception v2.  It turned out I had the wrong fine tune checkpoint in my model config file.  After I linked to the appropriate checkpoint for the model the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. Resolved by using a different checkpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You should either use checkpoints or to remove  "init_fn=init_fn" from slim.learning.train arguments and "initializer_fn" variable from trainer.
you can access all these from line around 393 in trainer